# set javascript variable toe evaluated viewbag expression

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I would like to set a javascript variable to the result of a viewbag expression. How can I do what this?

I know this is not right:

```
$scope.userPermissions = {
            manageUsers: '@ViewBag.IS_MANAGE_USER == 1',
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `manageUsers` to be a bool, i.e. `true` or `false` then you can do this:

```
    $scope.userPermissions = {
        manageUsers: @(ViewBag.IS_MANAGE_USER == 1 ? "true" : "false"),
    };
```